# Существительное "ответ" не согласовано с числительным "1" на странице вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Тут уже было много вопросов про согласование с числительными, но упоминания такого случая я не нашел.

<sub>[Согласно стандартам качества проекта, я должен расширить данный пост дополнительной информацией, поэтому могу также уточнить, что данное поведение (*1 ответов*) характерно и для meta.ru.SO]</sub>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправил.